# Line joining the intersections of perpendicular bisectors of opposite sides of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral which is not a parallelogram. Draw the line joining the intersection points of the perpendicular bisectors of the two pairs of the opposite sides of $ABCD$. Is it true that this line is parallel to the radical axis of the circles whose diameters are the diagonals of the quadrilateral?

I think somehow this is the case, leading to the fact that the line joining the two intersection points arisen by the four perpendicular bisectors is therefore perpendicular to the common chord of the two above-mentioned circles.

Thanks for any comment, hint, or solution!

Comment: What is the source of this problem? It's a little flawed: the two circles with the diagonals as diameters don't always have a common chord. That said, two circles always have a ["radical axis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis) that contains the common chord when that chord exists, so perhaps that makes a good replacement. Even so, a little experimentation with, say, [GeoGebra](http://geogebra.org) shows that the proposed concurrence doesn't happen in general. There's an interesting condition under which it *does* happen, though.

Comment: @Blue: I have edited the problem which makes a new hunch confirming my expressions following the problem's statement.

Comment: Since you've changed the nature of the question, I'll give the "interesting condition" I observed for the previous version: *If the diagonals of a non-parallelogram quadrilateral are congruent, then the perpendicular bisectors of opposite sides concur with the radical axis of the circles whose diameters are the diagonals of the quadrilateral.* (The quadrilateral need not be convex. Also, if the opposite sides are parallel —ie, the bases of an isosceles trapezoid— then the perpendicular bisectors actually coincide with the radical axis.)

Comment: By the way: The radical axis of two circles is perpendicular to the line joining their centers. Consequently, you can state your revised question without reference to circles at all. You're simply asking whether the points where the perpendicular bisectors of pairs of opposite sides of a quadrilateral meet determine a line perpendicular to the line joining the midpoints of the diagonals.